# How do I get the Xamarin build process to process my XAML files?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, msbuild

I have two Xamarin.Forms projects making use of XAML pages.  We'll call them ProjectOK and ProjectBroken.

ProjectOK builds okay.  ProjectBroken fails, saying it cannot find **InitializeComponent**.  Investigation (by increasing build output to Normal)  has revealed that this is because ProjectBroken is not processing my XAML files at all.  In the build output of ProjectOK, I get:

```
_CoreXamlG:
Source: Page1.xaml
Language: C#
AssemblyName: App1
OutputFile obj\Debug\App1.Page1.xaml.g.cs
```

ProjectBroken contains no such lines.

In Solution Explorer, the properties for the XAML pages in both projects are identical.  Page1.xaml file settings are: **Embedded Resource**, **Do not copy**, **Custom Tool=MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXAML**.  Page1.xaml.cs settings are: **Compile**, **Do not copy**.

Opening the project files, I find that ProjectOK contains:

```
<Compile Include="Page1.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Page1.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

And later:

```
<ItemGroup>
<EmbeddedResource Include="Page1.xaml">
    <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
    <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

ProjectBroken contains no references to my newly created Page1.xaml.

Even if I manually add the lines above to the ProjectBroken.csproj file, it still does not invoke the XAML compiler.

So, it seems that something is broken outside of my solution folder.  Does anyone have any idea what this might be, and - more importantly - how can I 'reset' it?

Comment: Check the x:Class tag on your xaml pages, I bet they don't match with the class/namespace on the code file...

Comment: That was the most common response when I Googled this problem. unfortunately, in this case, it is not the answer.  They are identical.

Comment: Is this an inherited page? maybe the namespaces are messed up.

Comment: Also, check the XAML dependency, look at this GIST, that's what you should see at your project, if the dependency is broken then the xaml will not be parsed: https://gist.github.com/gusmanb/f75a8731d0b050fa5452

Comment: @Gusman It is.  And I suspect that may be the problem, because a build I did earlier on ProjectBroken (which I can't duplicate) did run the XAML compiler and complained about a namespace that I thought I had fully deleted while trying to fix this problem.  UPDATE: the latest build on ProjectBroken is now running _CoreXamlG but it says it is skipping because it has no inputs.

Comment: Stupid question: did you tried to do a full clean to the solution and even reopen Xamarin Studio?

Comment: @Gusman The dependencies appear to be identical in both projects.

Comment: @Gusman I have done full cleans and even manually deleted all \obj and \bin folders. One important detail I forgot to mention is that I am using Xamarin inside Visual Studio 2015.  Sorry.

Comment: Hmmm, just for sanity, can you check it on XS? if that fails then you will have a better chance to get help on the Xamarin forums...

Comment: I think this is a Xamarin bug. If you delete all `obj` and `bin` folders and rebuild it usually fixes it for a short period

Comment: @Gusman In Xamarin on my Mac (so different tool, different hardware), I get the same result, ProjectBroken remains broken, ProjectOK is okay. So it is something hiding in the source files. Think I will start with ProjectOK and migrate files into it to see if I can spot when it breaks.  It will take a while but I should be able to spot something.  Incidentally, in ProjectBroken, the namespace has a period in it, while it doesn't in ProjectOK (e.g. ProjectOK has x:Class="App1.App", while ProjectBroken has x:Class="App1.Foo.App". Don't know if this could be breaking it.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure but may be worth to try to remove it, it can be perfectly a bug with namespaces on the Xaml parser. FYI, I just stomped with a very similar bug right now, I was changing XAML files and the changes didn't were reflected, finally I uninstalled the package from the emulator with ADB (i was testing on Android) and suddenly they worked again...